# Table Font Spacing

Tags: html, css, html-table

How do I make my table spacing slightly better so the words aren't on top of each other like in this screenshot:

I'm just using generic table HTML coding. Tried spacing and padding with the `tr` tag.

Comment: You want the [`line-height` CSS property](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/line-height), I think. Please post your code so we can be more specific about how to help you.

Comment: Roddy, that 100% was what I was looking for, i keep finding letter spacing. should have used the word "height" instead. thanks!

Comment: @JoshBartz, accept the given answer then. Next time, please post your code; your code had created the problem, but you did not disclose any part of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not problem with table spacing, you need to increase `line-height` for your text.